# Прокрутка webView до определенного элемента

Tags: java, android

Приветствую! Пилю приложение для просмотра сайта в webView, появилась задача при открытии программно прокручивать страницу до определенного элемента. webView.scrollTo() принимает на качестве параметров абсолютные значения, можно ли каким-то образом получить положение элемента(пусть даже загрузив html-код) или реализовать скролл каким-либо образом?

Comment: Элемент произвольный? Нет ли по близости подобного тэга-ссылки:  `<a name="anchor"></a>`, на который можно перейти добавив к адресу страницы `#anchor`

Comment: Элемент один - строка поиска на сайте, однако как обратиться к ней(к ее имени) из приложения, я не представляю

Comment: Хм... обычно поиск вверху и к нему не надо крутить. Можете привести этот кусок кода страницы или её адрес? На крайняк можно попытаться скриптом вставить такой якорь и потом на него перейти.

Comment: скриптом якорь - непосредственно в страницу? Привожу пример: данная страница в webView, имеет title, question, firstComment - как программно сделать скролл до firstComment? (очень условно)

Comment: Очень условно как-то так: `webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('firstComment').scrollIntoView();");` - выполнить после загрузки нужной страницы.

Comment: Понял вас, спасибо) а как думаете, есть возможность получить нэймы, т.е. id этих компонентов самостоятельно? запросил исходники сайта, для которого пишу, но может есть другой вариант

Comment: Сохраните страницу в файл и откройте любым текстовым редактором - вот Вам и исходник. То есть её можно скачать и сохранить как и любой другой файл.

Comment: Никак не могу заставить работать вашу строку, гугление не приносит пользы.. может, можно получить elementY?

Comment: Таким методом можно выполнить любой (в теории) javascript код `webView.loadUrl("javascript:" + "скрипт");`. Поэтому Вы можете найти другое решение на JS и применить. Не забудьте включить выполнение JS: `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`. Так же можно из JS вызвать java-код и передать туда какие-то данные (координаты нужного элемента, например). Начальную инфу можно почерпнуть в [доках](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#BindingJavaScript)

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что для выполнения JS скрипта из Java этот самый JS скипт должен быть описан внутри HTML страницы?

Comment: Необязательно. Можно загрузить его отдельно выше-приведённым способом после загрузки нужной страницы.

Answer (score 1):

upd спустя пару недель:
метод    webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('firstComment').scrollIntoView();");
отлично работает, если вставить в правильном месте ( в моем случае разместил в onPageFinished объекта webViewClient ).